# Getting sortBy in haskell to compare the first element

Tags: haskell

Hi so I have this pretty ugly list which looks like `[(Int,(String,Char))...]` and I want to use the `sortBy` function in Haskell to sort by the `Int`.

So far I have, `a` is the list

```
sorted = sortBy(comparing fst) a
```

but this gives the good old 'comparing' not in scope error message.
Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Add `import Data.Ord (comparing)` to your import list.

Comment: `comparing` is part of the `Data.Ord` module, which is not imported as part of the Prelude. You should `import Data.Ord`.

Comment: If you're familiar with the "good old" not in scope error messages then you should also be familiar with fixing them by importing things.

Comment: You can use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=comparing) to learn which module to import.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, `comparing` is exported by `Data.Ord`, so:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

a = [(2,"foo"),(1,"bar")]

main = print $ sortBy (comparing fst) a
```